# Hover state for corresponding product in unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onmouseover

I am working within an unordered list and separate list items. The menu consists of product images in the top list item and the corresponding product name in the list item below. I have a hover state on the bottom list items (product names). I am looking to make the same hover state active when hovering over the top list items (product images) as well. So, when I hover over /images/foo.png the link below in the separate list item will turn #ffffff. Below is the code I am working with. This is a small sample of a very large menu.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/products/">SPOUTS</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="menuheader"><a href="/products/spouts/index/">SPOUTS</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/products/spouts/foo/"><img src="/images/foo.png" style="margin:20px 0px 0px 20px;float:left;" /></a>
                <a href="/products/spouts/bar/"><img src="/images/bar.png" style="margin:20px 20px 0px 5px;float:left;" /></a>
                </li>
            <li style="margin-top:10px;">
                <a href="/products/spouts/foo/" style="float:left;margin-left:50px;">FOO</a> 
                <a href="/products/spouts/bar/" style="float:left;margin-left:60px;">BAR</a>
                </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: The question is when I hover over the image how do I get the corresponding product name to take on its hover state.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved with jQuery. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".YOUR_IMAGE").mouseenter(function (event) {
          $(".YOUR_LINK").addClass('hoverState');
     });

     $(".YOUR_IMAGE").mouseleave(function (event) {
          $(".YOUR_LINK").removeClass('hoverState');
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Would I put a class on each individual image? I'm sorry but could you possibly adjust the http://jsfiddle.net/d4gey/ accordingly. I am a little lost. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you would copy the code above for each image/link combination. You would want to put a unique class on each email and link.